# Flutter GETX: How to remove Initialized Controller every time we navigate to other page/routes

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

newbie here. How do I re-run onInit() every time I push back to my screen? onInit() runs only once but navigating back to a previous screen does not delete the controller which was initialized (**FetchData**) hmmm..

I'm only using **Get.back()** every time I want to pop page, and
**Get.toNamed()** every time I want to navigate on a named  route

the only thing I want to happen is to delete the Initialized controller (**FetchData**) every time I pop the page
but I have no Idea how to do it.

my **GetxController**

```
class FetchData extends GetxController {
    RxList items = [].obs;
    @override
    onInit() {
      fetchData();
      super.onInit();
    }
    
    Future<void> fetchData() async {
     var result = await http.get("api.url");
     items.value = result.body;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not enough information is given. You need to also provide your bindings and view snippets to get proper help

Answer (score 14):

You can use:

```
Get.delete<FetchData>();
```

Answer (score 7):

When I logout Get.off, Get.offUntil, Get.offAndToNamed methods doesnt remove my GetXController from memory.

then I tried below code and everything works fine.

```
 Get.offUntil(GetPageRoute(page: () => Login()), ModalRoute.withName('toNewLogin') );
   
     Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 300), ()=>Get.delete<MainPageController>());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
Get.deleteAll();
```

This will **remove all** the **Initialized controllers instances** from your memory.

Answer (score 2):

The onInit is only called once. You can use another method to run when back from another screen, for example, when call the new screen you can await until it closes and then call your method again:

```
//go to new screen
await Get.toNamed(screenName);
//after run my method
controller.fectchData();
```

if you want call the method only in some cases you can pass a bool back to ask if needs reload:

```
Get.back(result: true);
```

and in the screen that called:

```
//go to new screen
final result = await Get.toNamed(screenName);
    
if(result != null && result == true)//after run only if needed
controller.fectchData();
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put method `fetchData()` on `super.onInit()`. When you use `Get.offAllName()`, `Get.offAndToName()`, `Get.offAll()`, etc... Method `fetchData()` is still kept in memory => Cannot `dispose` or `close` it.

FIX:

```
class FetchData extends GetxController {
   RxList items = [].obs;
   @override
   onInit() {
     super.onInit(); // <--- swap code here
     fetchData(); // <--- swap code here
   }

   Future<void> fetchData() async {
      var result = await http.get("api.url");
      items.value = result.body;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Get.offAndToNamed(url)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use Get.offAllNamed. It will remove all controllers and create only the final destination route controller. Tested with get: ^4.3.8

```
        Get.offAllNamed("your final route");
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is `Get.delete<FetchData>();` if you had created like `Get.put(FetchData())`

But If you have created like `Get.put(FetchData(), permanent: true);` or by `LazyPut` you can delete that by forcing `Get.delete<FetchData>(force: true);`

I hope this helps you.