# How to delete all Getx controllers at once?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have a Flutter project, and I want to delete all `Getx`'s `GetxController` that I injected using:

```
Get.put(/*...*/);
Get.lazyPut(/*...*/);
```

is this possible with Getx, and how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter GETX: How to remove Initialized Controller every time we navigate to other page/routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67250736/flutter-getx-how-to-remove-initialized-controller-every-time-we-navigate-to-oth) ?

Comment: no, I want a way to delete all controllers that I inject in the entire app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Get.deleteAll();
```

Comment: duplicate answer?

Comment: Exactly what I searched for, thank you

Comment: @MyCar, it's the same question that i marked this question as duplicate.

Comment: @Gwhyyy, lol and you said simply no without actually checking answers from the marked duplicate question.

Comment: so sorry, I didn't notice the last answers

Comment: I accepted it as a duplicate, again I'm sorry

Comment: It's okay, relax ☺️